# PhpStorm method not found in subject class

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have a separate class that establishes PDO connection:

```
class Core {
    public $dbh; // handle of the db connection
    private static $instance;

    private function __construct()  {
        // building data source name from config
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . Config::read('db.host') . ';dbname=' . Config::read('db.basename') . ';port=' . Config::read('db.port') .';charset=' . Config::read('db.charset') . ';connect_timeout=15';
        //echo '$dsn is '.$dsn;

        // getting DB user from config
        $user = Config::read('db.user');

        // getting DB password from config
        $password = Config::read('db.password');

        $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
        $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->dbh->exec("set names utf8mb4");
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            $object = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $object;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    /** @method PDO */
    public function getPdo() {
        $core = $this->getInstance();
        $pdo = $core->dbh;
        return $pdo;
    }
}
```

Now, each time I'm reading from or writing to the db in another class (e. g. `$compared_text = Core::getInstance()->getPdo()->query($query_text)->fetchColumn();`), even though everything works, PhpStorm says "Referenced method is not found in subject class" regarding the method `getPdo()`.

I googled and came across some answers here on Stackoverflow that suggested using PhpDocs, and, as you can see, I added a comment `/** @method PDO */` before the function `getPdo()`, but it still throws this warning. What's the issue?

### UPD

The warning goes away if I write `$compared_text = Core::getInstance()->Core::getPdo()->query($query_text)->fetchColumn();`.

So now my question is as follows:

Can I make the warning go away without explicitly writing `Core::` before calling each method from it? If no, I'm just going to ignore the warning (don't want to disable it though).

Comment: Maybe annotate getInstance() with the return type.

Comment: It worked, wanna post it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate the return type of the `getInstance()` method like this

```
/**
 * @return Core
 */
public static function getInstance() {
    if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
        $object = __CLASS__;
        self::$instance = new $object;
    }
    return self::$instance;
}
```

The IDE will read that annotation.

Comment: Even better use type hinting `public static function getInstance() : Core {`